# Why is my microsoft visual studio always busy?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I am currently trying to do an SISS project using microsoft visual studio. However, after i edit the project for no more then 1 minute, the software suddenly says Microsoft is delayed or busy... Because of some operations. The software will sometimes also freeze and dont let me do anything

For the first comment:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFAUy.png)

Comment: Find any clue in the processes tab in Task Manager.

Comment: No clue... It looks normal

Comment: Add a screenshot of the error message.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Where have you got stuck? [superuser.com/help/how-to-ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)